# How to build a sequential logic circuit with transistors on a breadboard

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

I'm helping out a student with his homework, which includes building logic gates with transistors on a breadboard, and so far I've successfully built NOT, NOR, NAND, and NOR/NAND logic circuits.

However, the last question is to build this sequential logic circuit on a breadboard, and so far nothing is happening (the LED doesn't light up):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmjSnI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the above schematic, Node 1 and Node 2 are inputs (either 0 or 1 depending on whether a switch button is pressed) and Node 3 is the output, which is an LED (so presumably it should light up on some kind of combination of inputs).

> My NOR gate (which works correctly) is wired up like this:

**transistor 1 left:** gnd

**transistor 1 middle:** switch > 10k resistor > 5v

**transistor 1 right:** connected to the right of transistor 2; connected to 1K resistor then 5V; connected to LED then gnd

**transistor 2 left:** gnd

**transistor 2 middle:** switch > 10k resistor > 5v

**transistor 2 right:** connected to the right of transistor 1

I then made *two* NOR gates which I need to modify to make the sequential logic diagram above. Right now I have it wired like this, but it's NOT working:

> NOR gate 1:

**transistor 1 left:** gnd

**transistor 1 middle:** switch > 10k resistor > 5v

**transistor 1 right:** connected to the right of transistor 2; connected to 1K resistor then 5V; connected to LED then gnd; connected to NOR gate 2 transistor 2 in the middle

**transistor 2 left:** gnd

**transistor 2 middle:** connected to NOR gate 2, transistor 1 right

**transistor 2 right:** connected to the right of transistor 1

> NOR gate 2:

**transistor 1 left:** gnd

**transistor 1 middle:** switch > 10k resistor > 5v

**transistor 1 right:** connected to the right of transistor 2; connected to 1K resistor then 5V; connected to NOR gate 1 transistor 2 in the middle

**transistor 2 left:** gnd

**transistor 2 middle:** connected to NOR gate 1, transistor 1 right

**transistor 2 right:** connected to the right of transistor 1

If none of my description makes any sense, can someone just tell me what the expected output for the LED should be? I have two switches, so I can put in 00, 01, 10, and 11 as inputs. What should happen to the LED in those cases?

Edit: Here's my best attempt at a schematic for the sequential logic circuit. Transistors may be flipped around, not sure, but the sides I picked should be consistent (I know which side is which on my breadboard.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl70Dp.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbBKaq.png)</sup>

*Tidy-up of schematic edited in by @transistor. I have assumed transistors C and E were reversed in each case.*

Comment: A schematic of what you actually built would help.

Comment: Added my best guess of what the schematic is (transistors may be flipped, not sure)

Comment: Hmm, sorry but that schematic is a bit of a mess. If you google for "NOR gate schematic" and search for images. You will see some more readable examples of what such a schematic might look like. Having a readable schematic will also help in getting the circuit right.

Comment: If the down-pointing arrows indicate Ground/negative, then the transistors are backwards.  The arrows in the transistor symbol should point towards the negative side of the power supply (which is usually considered "Ground/Zero volts").  Show where the unconnected ends of the voltage sources connect.

Comment: @Ginny: See my answer to [Question about RS flip-flop](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223458/question-about-rs-flip-flop) asked a few hours ago.

Comment: @Ginny: I've redrawn your schematic for you. Maybe it will make more sense now but I don't see how it's ever supposed to work. Where did you get the design? It has exactly the same problem as the one in the link above.

Comment: The down arrows are ground; it comes from the schematic maker that is provided by stack exchange. I didn't get the schematic from anywhere, I tried to make it based on how I wired my breadboard (I totally admit I don't know how to make a schematic.)

Comment: My attempt at a schematic can be totally ignored; really all I'm looking for is how to wire the very top circuit (with the two nor gates) on my breadboard. Or, at the minimum, when I should expect the LED to light up. Thanks!

Comment: @transistor Thanks, that link helped me! I built that flip flop circuit, and then modified it for the circuit above with 1 LED. However, I built it with only two transistors, so now my new question is should I have 2 or 4 transistors? I thought a NOR gate was supposed to have two transistors.

Comment: Add a schematic at the bottom of your post to show us what you built.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the redrawn schematic is an accurate representation of what you actually built, then the problem is that you have the LED connected directly in parallel with the B-E junction of Q2.

The circuit is working, but Q2 prevents the voltage across the LED from rising high enough to light it up.

The fix would be to make the connection between the base of Q2 and the LED using another 10 kΩ resistor. This will limit the current into Q2's base and allow the LED to light up.